# Stuck on Raspi-Config

Tags: boot, keyboard

I recently re-installed Raspian. Before it was working without a hitch. Now when I boot it up for the first time, it gets to the Raspi-Config screen and I can't go anywhere because the keyboard doesn't work. It is the same keyboard that I used on it before, it's even the keyboard I'm using now. I also have tried other keyboard.

I then looked up the problem, people with the same problem have reported that it's a power problem so I made sure I had `5V and 1A` and I tried that with multiple power supplies. Nothing.

Can anyone suggest a reasoning?

Comment: I would try to configure my Keyboard using SSH (PuTTY, if you're using windows).

Comment: Does the keyboard get power? i.e. does numlock/caps lock light go on or off, that to me would suggest power is ok, in either case, i'd go with @Tico suggestion of using SSH to run raspi-config

Comment: @kolin Just a reminder: I use a Logitech K800, it requires a receiver and it always worked fine. I don't see power as a problem.

Comment: Can you see if the keyboard registered on startup?

Answer (score 1):

The Pi uses 5W just for itself (5V and 1A). Therefore you need more amps to power a keyboard as well. Use `5V 1.6A` and this hopefully will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

As exantas mentioned, the Pi uses 5W just for itself. What I would do is get a powered USB hub. You can also get a power supply with more amps, like exantas suggested, but a powered USB hub will allow you to use mice, flash drives, wifi adapters, and other power-drawing peripherals easily.

Good Luck!